# How do I edit the dendrogram whilst using heatmap.2 function in r

Tags: r

I am trying to create a `heatmap` to represent the change of gene expression over a period of time. the code I have used is this:

```
coul <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(8, "Reds"))(25)
heatmap.2(dm, dendogram=c("row"),Colv=NA, xlab="Time points", ylab="Genes of interest", scale="row", col=coul, tracecol = NA)
```

As one cant really see the branches of the `dendogram` that well, I was wondering whether you can somehow stretch it out to become more visible?

I was also wondering how to remove the "colour key and histogram" label.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you don't mind the color guide being wide, you just use the lwid option, you specify a vector that decides the ratio of dendrogram to heatmap, below I use c(3,3), which means 1:1.

```
set.seed(100)
x = matrix(rnorm(1000),100,10)
heatmap.2(x,trace="none",Colv=NA,dendrogram=c("row"),tracecol = NA)
```

[image]

```
heatmap.2(x,trace="none",Colv=NA,
dendrogram=c("row"),lwid=c(3,3),tracecol = NA,keysize=0.75)
```

[image]

One way to narrow the margins of the color guide is to use key.par, where you set the margins on the right to be larger (I use 10 in example below).

```
heatmap.2(x,trace="none",Colv=NA,dendrogram=c("row"),
lwid=c(3,3),tracecol = NA,keysize=0.75,key.par=list(mar=c(3,3,3,10)))
```